# Add scrollbar to modal window

Tags: html, css

I have a site similar to fullPage.js where the page only covers the screen, no scrollbar with other words. However, the site contains links to modal windows with different kind of contents. What I wonder is if it's possible to make these modals scrollable considering that the rest of the site isn't.

If I force a vertical scrollbar I get the scrollbar on the site but, however, can't use it for some reason.

Here is the modal window:

```js
$('#video-pop').click(function() {
  $('#open-menu').fadeIn(350);
});

$('#close-menu').click(function() {
  $('#open-menu').fadeOut(350);
});
```

```css
#open-menu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 60;
  background: #060606;
  display: none;
}

.menu-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#close-menu {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="video-pop">OPEN PAGE</div>
<div id="open-menu">
  <div class="menu-content">
    <div id="close-menu">CLOSE PAGE</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/neaqs3bv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have it here, a scrollbar will never appear because `open-menu` just fills the remaining part of the screen and `menu-content` fills `open-menu`. In other words, there will never be any overflow that needs scrolling to.

In order to make the scrollbars appear, make the height of `menu-content` larger than the height of `open-menu` and add `overflow-y: auto` to `open-menu`. Here's an example:

```
#open-menu {
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height: 50%;
  z-index: 60;
  background: #060606;
  display: none;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.menu-content {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
}

#close-menu {
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 250px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oze4wv1v/

Answer (score 2):

Your `#open-menu` may have specified scrolling styles like that:

```
#open-menu {
    /* ... your styles */
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```